# Jquery slidedown file not responding

Tags: jquery

What I'm trying to do is slide down a form once the a Href link has been hit. This function has been saved in another a external folder called formValidation.js.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#register').slidedown(800);
}

<head>
<title> <?php $page_title ?> </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
   <script src="formValidation.js"></script>
   <script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>   

   <div id="nav">

     <ul>

        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="register.php">Register</a></li>
        <li><a href="film.php">Film</a></li>

<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']) and isset($_SESSION['name']))
{
  echo "<li><a href='review_a_film.php'>Review a film</a></li>";
}
?>

        <li><a href="logout.php">logout</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </head>
<body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok 1st issue is that your FormValidatoin is above your Jquery file.

The Jquery file takes precedence over the custom function.

script src="jquery-1.10.2.js">

script src="formValidation.js">

2nd issue is the lowecase letter on the .slidedown event ( .slideDown ).

```
$('#register').slidedown(800);
```

Also to make a element slide you must first give that elememt a CSS style of

```
 #register{
display: none;
```

}

Hope this helps.